# How to add custom cursor

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouse-cursor

Im trying to add a custom cursor to this game I'm trying to make
here is the code

```java
    JFrame window = new JFrame("First Java Window");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    

    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    
    window.add(gamePanel);
    
    Image cursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("cursor.png"));
    Point hotSpot = new Point(0,0);
    Cursor cursorInGame = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(cursor, hotSpot, "name");
    window.setCursor(cursorInGame);
   
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
    gamePanel.startGameThread();
```

when i run the code it opens everything and the cursor is blank

Comment: Set the cursor on the `gamePanel` itself. I would also consider using `ImageIO.read` instead of `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage` so if the image can't be loaded for some reason it will tell you

Comment: So, I did quick test - my guess is `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("cursor.png"));` isn't loading the image (failing silent), so I suggest changing it with `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("cursor.png"))` and catching the exception it throws to verify that the image is been loaded